# Dividing counts of rows with different categories in Impala

Tags: sql, view, hive, aggregate-functions, impala

Hi I have table like this and would like to construct views for getting the rate of sums(counts) for each type.
**For each type, I would like to divide the sum of counts with NULL in "cat" and sum of counts with non-null value in "cat"**

This is my query which give me incorrect results (I think because I need to sum the counts first, but Im struggling to do so)

```
select case   
    When protocol = 61002 AND type= 3 THEN   "S11 Success Rate" 
    When protocol= 61002 AND type = 4 THEN   "S11 Bearer Success Rate"  
end as name,  
max(case when cat is null then count end ) / nullif(max(case when cat is not null then count end),0) as result  
from table
```

using this table:

[image]

The desired result for type 3 would be result=(63+15456) **/** (51609+18127)=0.2225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this is what you are looking for:

```
select 
case
    When protocol = 61002 AND type = 3 THEN "S11 Success Rate" 
    When protocol = 61002 AND type = 4 THEN "S11 Bearer Success Rate"
end as name,
sum(case when cat is null then count else 0 end)/sum(case when cat is null then 0 else count end)
from table
group by name
```

This produces the following result:

> S11 Success Rate  0.22253929104049558
>
> S11 Bearer Success Rate   0.90956749672346004

Grouping makes sure you can aggregate by type.
The case statement sets the value to 0 when it is not in the correct case. This results in the correct sum you expected.

Comment: Yes, solved that this morning, thanks for the input!